# what can be used instead of new uiviewcontrollers

Tags: ios, ipad

I am developing an iOS app which have 3 main uiviewcontrollers and more than 50 different forms.

I completed designing main forms (login, form selection and message uiviewcontrollers). User will select any form and related form will be loaded. But I do not want to use tab or tableview controller and create more than 50 viewcontrollers in my application. Because all contents are amost same (including a long text and one button).

I would like to create something like subviews (I use usercontrol (ascx) in .net web apps) or or anything else. but do not want to create many viewcontrollers.
What can I use for my forms?  Then I will load the content by user selection.

Can you help me?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You already answered it yourself. You need only 1 viewcontroller with a textview and a button, only the content changes.

Comment: If a lot of the forms are the same, just use one VC and include the required fields programmatically. Dynamic content based on what you need at a given time.

Comment: hi sangony, could you please provide/advice me a sample? or web site including an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could 'group' the forms and see which elements stick together a lot.
Make those subviews of UIView in code and re-use them by adding them programmatically to populate your VC.

Comment: Sorry Jasper,I could not understand what you mean with "group the forms". Do you mean subviews for forms? Can you provide any link for at least a simple sample?

Comment: I mean: some forms will have some elements which are the same, like date, name, ... Group those together and make them small UIView's so you can re-use them in other forms.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your application, you should present your forms as [ModalViewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html). This way you will present the forms when needed and dismiss them once "Submit" is hit for example. Then the form can pass information to its delegate (which can be the main view controller) through a delegate method.

Here's a good tutorial on using ModalViewControllers: "[Presenting View Controllers](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/10/08/presenting-view-controllers.html)"